# Java StringIndexOutOfBounds When Using Substring

Tags: java, string, int, runtime-error, substring

I get a StringIndexOutOfBounds error with this Java program on the line:

```
String num3 = lottoString.substring(2,2);
```

Telling me that 2 is out of the range, but this code should randomly pick a three digit lottery number ranging from 000 through 999. What is my error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lottery
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Declare and initialize variables and objects
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lottoString = "";

        //Generate a 3-digit "lottery" number composed of random numbers
        //Simulate a lottery by drawing one number at a time and 
        //concatenating it to the string
        //Identify the repeated steps and use a for loop structure
        for(int randomGen=0; randomGen < 3; randomGen++){
            int lotNums = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            lottoString = Integer.toString(lotNums);
        }

        String num1 = lottoString.substring(0,0);
        String num2 = lottoString.substring(1,1);
        String num3 = lottoString.substring(2,2);

        String num12 = num1 + num2;
        String num23 = num2 + num3;
        String num123 = num1 + num2 + num3;

        //Input: Ask user to guess 3 digit number
        System.out.println("Please enter your three numbers (e.g. 123): ");
        String userGuess = input.next();

        //Compare the user's guess to the lottery number and report results
        if(userGuess.equals(num123)){
            System.out.println("Winner: " + num123);
            System.out.println("Congratulations, both pairs matched!");
        }else if(userGuess.substring(0,2).equals(num12)){
            System.out.println("Winner: " + num123);
            System.out.println("Congratulations, the front pair matched!");
        }else if(userGuess.substring(1,3).equals(num23)){
            System.out.println("Winner: " + num123);
            System.out.println("Congratulations, the end pair matched!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Winner: " + num123);
            System.out.println("Sorry, no matches! You only had one chance out of 100 to win anyway.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a line to print out the length of the string just before you do the substring op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, every time you iterate over your loop, you reset the value of `lottoString` to just be one digit. You need to *append* to it, like this:

```
lottoString += Integer.toString(lotNums);
```

Your other problem is your use of the `substring` method. If both index positions are the same, such as `0,0`, it returns an empty String. What you want is this:

```
String num1 = lottoString.substring(0,1);
String num2 = lottoString.substring(1,2);
String num3 = lottoString.substring(2,3);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I thought 3 wouldn't work since there's only 3 digits and the counting is weird with them

Comment: @user2337438 Yup, in the official documentation it says: `The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int randomGen=0; randomGen < 3; randomGen++){
    int lotNums = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    lottoString = Integer.toString(lotNums);
}
```

You're assignining the result of Integer.toString() to lottoString. lotNums is a number between 0 and 9.

I guess you want

```
lottoString += Integer.toString(lotNums);
```